# Why is my bash script getting "Killed"? How do I prevent that?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have written a bash script to test student written C programs against a test-suite. For some reason the script is getting Killed after a while. I'm a novice in bash scripting and till now has not found the reason. Here's the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -t 1
tests_dir=tests
run_dir=tests
find . -name "*.c" | while read cfile; do rm a.out &> /dev/null; gcc "$cfile" -lm -w &> /dev/null;
if [ ! -f a.out ]; 
then 
    echo "$cfile did-not-compile" >> "$run_dir/results.out";
else
    find "$tests_dir" -name "in*.txt" | while read testin; do echo "running $testin on $cfile"; 
    rm test.out &> /dev/null; 
    rm space_less_testout &> /dev/null;
    LD_PRELOAD=../../EasySandbox/EasySandbox.so ./a.out < $testin | grep -v "entering SECCOMP mode" &> test.out;
    if [ -e test.out ]; then
            testout=${testin/in/out}
            tr -d '\n' < $testout | tr -d ' ' > space_less_testout
            echo -e '\n' >> space_less_testout

            if diff -qwB "$testout" test.out &> /dev/null
            then
                    # if no difference then takes true brance (based on return value)
                    echo "$cfile ;passed-on-test; $testin" >> "$run_dir/results.out"; echo "passed-on-test $testin";
            elif diff -qB space_less_testout test.out &> /dev/null 
            then
                    # or no difference with new-line removed should-be-output (just a formatting error)
                    echo "$cfile ;passed-on-test; $testin" >> "$run_dir/results.out"; echo "passed-on-test $testin";
            else
                    echo "$cfile ;failed-on-test; $testin" >> "$run_dir/results.out"; echo "failed-on-test $testin";
            fi
    fi
done;
fi
done;
```

Comment: You could run `strace` or `bash -x` on it to see where it timeouts. It might also be getting killed by OOM Killer if you run out of memory

Comment: I don't think `LD_PRELOAD` is a secure way to implement a sandbox.

Comment: @kasperd I'm not an expert but I'm following https://github.com/daveho/EasySandbox

Comment: @rahuL From your link there is already one [exploit](https://github.com/daveho/EasySandbox/issues/3) documented. The proposed workaround for that exploit is to avoid linking the `dl` library required for loading dynamic libraries. But if the executable can get to run code before `SECCOMP` mode is activated it does not need any libraries to do harm. One can use inline assembly to make system calls directly from C code without needing any libraries. Example: `__asm__ __volatile__("syscall": "=a"(fd): "a"(2), "D"("/tmp/gotcha"), "S"(O_CREAT|O_WRONLY), "d"(0644));`

Comment: @kasperd Okay. I'll see what other options are there. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ulimit -t 1` limits the script's CPU time to 1 second. When the script has consumed all its CPU time it gets killed.

To limit the CPU time of just one command in your script you can use parentheses to start it in a subshell with its own limit, e.g.

```
(ulimit -t 1; LD_PRELOAD=../../EasySandbox/EasySandbox.so ./a.out < $testin)
```

Comment: But then how do I limit the execution time of student code? I had tried setting limit to 1 second before test-case execution and the increasing it again. But increasing ulimit -t is not allowed it seems.

Comment: Added that to my answer.